# LEFT JOIN Table A depends on Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a block user system:

**Table A:**

```
-------------------
id_user | username 
-------------------
   1    |    A
-------------------
   2    |    B
-------------------
   3    |    C
-------------------
   4    |    D
-------------------

.... and so on
```

**Table B:**

```
--------------------------------------
id_block | user_request | user_banned 
--------------------------------------
   1    |       1       |      2
--------------------------------------
   2    |       1       |      3
--------------------------------------
... and so on
```

**Case #1:** When the User A get the user list from Table A so is User B and User C hidden from him.

**Case #2:** When the User B get the user list from Table A so is User A hidden from him.

**Case #3:** When the User C get the user list from Table A so is User A hidden from him.

**Case #4:** When the User D get the user list from Table A so it getting all the users.

So far I've tried this:

```
SELECT t1.id_user, t1.username

FROM user t1

  LEFT JOIN block_user t2

    ON (t2.user_request = 1 AND t2.user_banned = 1)

WHERE t1.id_user NOT IN

    (SELECT user_request FROM block_user WHERE user_request = 1 )

  AND t1.id_user NOT IN 

    (SELECT user_banned FROM block_user WHERE user_banned = 1)
```

The result are User B and C are hidden! Great!

But, when you change the User Id to example 2 then are User A and C hidden. Not great, should be only User A hidden!

When you change the User Id to 4 then is User A, B and C hidden.

I make some example for this case:

[**sqlfiddle User ID 1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02377/103)

[**sqlfiddle User ID 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02377/105)

[**sqlfiddle User ID 3**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02377/106)

[**sqlfiddle User ID 4**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02377/102)

P.D. I know, I can make two querys to have a solution for this, but there must be a solution for this.

Comment: [there ya go](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02377/111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id_user, t1.username
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN block_user t2
ON 
   (t2.user_request = <current user id> AND t2.user_banned = t1.id_user)
   OR
   (t2.user_request = t1.id_user AND t2.user_banned = <current user id>)
WHERE t2.id_block IS NULL;
```

[see the fiddle in action for A, B, C & D](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02377/111)